High chart is not displaying in android device
I have api to get the data from API, the API is SOAP API, So I am using the AsyncTask to get the data. This is the class I am using to get the data
new UsagegraphServ(getActivity(), new String[]{"07/30/2024"}, "Get60minIntervalUsageData").execute();

After successfull to get the data in onPostExecute, I am calling the below methods to display the chart.
setupGraph(GraphType.NULL);
setupGraph(GraphType.INIT); 

The following is the full code
private void setupGraph(GraphType type) { // type for preload chart view

        try {
            int columnWidth = 20;
            int columnSpace = 10;
            double maxNegativeUsage = 0;
            float minWeather = 0;

            chartView.theme = "grid-light";

            //map to list of usagemodel
            List<String> dateFormatList = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Float> amountList = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Float> usageList = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Float> demanUsageList = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Float> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Float> humidityList = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Float> heatIndexList = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Float> windSpeedList = new ArrayList<>();

            List<String> usageColorList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < usgListParsedVals.size(); i++) {
                dateFormatList.add(usgListParsedVals.get(i).get("UsageHourDateFormat"));

                if (usgListParsedVals.get(i).get("KWH").equalsIgnoreCase("nan"))
                    usageList.add(Float.parseFloat("0"));
                else
                    usageList.add(Float.parseFloat(usgListParsedVals.get(i).get("KWH")));

                if (usgListParsedVals.get(i).get("Temp").equalsIgnoreCase("nan"))
                    tempList.add(Float.parseFloat("0"));
                else
                    tempList.add(Float.parseFloat(usgListParsedVals.get(i).get("Temp")));

                if (usgListParsedVals.get(i).get("Humidity").equalsIgnoreCase("nan"))
                    humidityList.add(Float.parseFloat("0"));
                else
                    humidityList.add(Float.parseFloat(usgListParsedVals.get(i).get("Humidity")));

                if (usgListParsedVals.get(i).get("HeatIndex").equalsIgnoreCase("nan"))
                    heatIndexList.add(Float.parseFloat("0"));
                else
                    heatIndexList.add(Float.parseFloat(usgListParsedVals.get(i).get("HeatIndex")));

                if (usgListParsedVals.get(i).get("WindSpeed").equalsIgnoreCase("nan"))
                    windSpeedList.add(Float.parseFloat("0"));
                else
                    windSpeedList.add(Float.parseFloat(usgListParsedVals.get(i).get("WindSpeed")));

                usageColorList.add(usgListParsedVals.get(i).get("GraphColor"));

                strColorKwh = usgListParsedVals.get(0).get("GraphColor");
                strColorTemp = usgListParsedVals.get(0).get("TempGraphColor");
                strColorHumidity = usgListParsedVals.get(0).get("HumidityGraphColor");
                strColorHeat = usgListParsedVals.get(0).get("HeatIndexGraphColor");
                strColorWind = usgListParsedVals.get(0).get("WindSpeedGraphColor");

            }
            Log.e("Date ", "@@@" + dateFormatList.size());
            Log.e("usage ", "@@@" + usageList.size());

            HIOptions options = new HIOptions();
            options.setCredits(new HICredits());
            options.setExporting(new HIExporting());
            options.getCredits().setEnabled(false);
            options.getExporting().setEnabled(false);
            options.setColors(new ArrayList<>(usageColorList));


            int minWidth = (columnWidth + columnSpace) * dateFormatList.size();

            HIChart chart = new HIChart();
            chart.setScrollablePlotArea(new HIScrollablePlotArea());
            chart.getScrollablePlotArea().setMinWidth(minWidth);
            chart.getScrollablePlotArea().setScrollPositionX(0);

            options.setChart(chart);

            HITitle title = new HITitle();
            title.setText(""); // Chart Top Title
            options.setTitle(title);

            HISubtitle subtitle = new HISubtitle();
            subtitle.setText(""); // Chart second top title
            options.setSubtitle(subtitle);

            HIXAxis xaxis = new HIXAxis();
            if (type == GraphType.NULL) {
                xaxis.setCategories(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList()));
            } else {
                xaxis.setCategories(new ArrayList<>(dateFormatList));
            }

            options.setXAxis(new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(xaxis)));

            HIYAxis yaxis = new HIYAxis();
            yaxis.setMin(maxNegativeUsage);
            yaxis.setStackLabels(new HIStackLabels());
            yaxis.getStackLabels().setEnabled(true);

            HITitle titleYaxis = new HITitle();
            HICSSObject titleStyle = new HICSSObject();
            //titleStyle.setColor(HIColor.initWithHexValue("#0E6F81"));
            titleYaxis.setStyle(titleStyle);
            titleYaxis.setText("Usage (kwh)");
            yaxis.setTitle(titleYaxis);

            HILabels hiLabelsYaxisOpposite = new HILabels();
            hiLabelsYaxisOpposite.setEnabled(true);

            HIYAxis yaxisOpposite = new HIYAxis();
            yaxisOpposite.setMin(minWeather);
            yaxisOpposite.setTitle(new HITitle());
//            yaxisOpposite.getTitle().setText(""); // Chart Left Title yaxis.getTitle().setText("Usage (Kwh)"); // Chart Left Title
            yaxisOpposite.setOpposite(true);
            yaxisOpposite.setType("temp");
            yaxisOpposite.setLabels(new HILabels());
            yaxisOpposite.getLabels().setFormat("{value}°F");

            HITitle titleYaxis1 = new HITitle();
            HICSSObject titleStyle1 = new HICSSObject();
            titleYaxis1.setStyle(titleStyle1);
            titleYaxis1.setRotation(270);
            titleYaxis1.setText("temperature (°F)");
//            titleYaxis1.setText("");
            yaxisOpposite.setTitle(titleYaxis1);
            yaxisOpposite.setOpposite(true);

            options.setYAxis(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(yaxis, yaxisOpposite)));

            HILegend legend = new HILegend();
            legend.setEnabled(false);
            options.setLegend(legend);

            HITooltip tooltip = new HITooltip();
//            tooltip.setPointFormat("{series.name} <b>{point.y}</b><br/>");
            tooltip.setPointFormat("kWh: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>");
            tooltip.setHeaderFormat("Date: {point.x}<br/>");
            options.setTooltip(tooltip);
//            tooltip.setEnabled(false);

            HIPlotOptions plotoptions = new HIPlotOptions();
            plotoptions.setColumn(new HIColumn());
            plotoptions.getColumn().setStacking("normal");
            plotoptions.getColumn().setPointWidth(20);
            plotoptions.getColumn().setColorByPoint(true);

            options.setPlotOptions(plotoptions);

 

            HISpline tempSpline = new HISpline();
            tempSpline.setName("Temp:");
            tempSpline.setData(new ArrayList<>(tempList));
            tempSpline.setTooltip(new HITooltip());
            tempSpline.setColor(HIColor.initWithName(strColorTemp));
            tempSpline.setYAxis(1);
            tempSpline.setTooltip(new HITooltip());
            tempSpline.getTooltip().setValueSuffix("°F");

            HISpline humiditySpline = new HISpline();
            humiditySpline.setName("Humidity:");
            humiditySpline.setData(new ArrayList<>(humidityList));
            humiditySpline.setTooltip(new HITooltip());
            humiditySpline.setColor(HIColor.initWithName(strColorHumidity));
            humiditySpline.setYAxis(1);
            humiditySpline.setTooltip(new HITooltip());
            humiditySpline.getTooltip().setValueSuffix("°F");

            HISpline heatSpline = new HISpline();
            heatSpline.setName("Humidity:");
            heatSpline.setData(new ArrayList<>(humidityList));
            heatSpline.setTooltip(new HITooltip());
            heatSpline.setColor(HIColor.initWithName(strColorHeat));
            heatSpline.setYAxis(1);
            heatSpline.setTooltip(new HITooltip());
            heatSpline.getTooltip().setValueSuffix("°F");

            HISpline windSpline = new HISpline();
            windSpline.setName("Humidity:");
            windSpline.setData(new ArrayList<>(humidityList));
            windSpline.setTooltip(new HITooltip());
            windSpline.setColor(HIColor.initWithName(strColorWind));
            windSpline.setYAxis(1);
            windSpline.setTooltip(new HITooltip());
            windSpline.getTooltip().setValueSuffix("°F");

            HIColumn column1 = new HIColumn();

            if (type == GraphType.NULL) {
                column1.setName("");
                tempSpline.setData(new ArrayList<>());
                humiditySpline.setData(new ArrayList<>());
                column1.setData(new ArrayList<>());
            } else {
                column1.setData(new ArrayList<>(usageList));
            }

            ArrayList seriesList = new ArrayList();
            if (usageList.size() != 0) {
                seriesList.add(column1);

                if (showLegendTemp)
                    seriesList.add(tempSpline);

                if (showLegendHumidity)
                    seriesList.add(humiditySpline);

                if (showLegendHeat)
                    seriesList.add(heatSpline);

                if (showLegendWind)
                    seriesList.add(windSpline);
            }

            cardViewKwh.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(strColorKwh));

            if (showLegendTemp)
                cardViewTemp.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(strColorTemp));
            else
                cardViewTemp.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(strColorUnSelect));

            if (showLegendHumidity)
                cardViewHumidity.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(strColorHumidity));
            else
                cardViewHumidity.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(strColorUnSelect));

            if (showLegendHeat)
                cardViewHeat.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(strColorHeat));
            else
                cardViewHeat.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(strColorUnSelect));

            if (showLegendWind)
                cardViewWind.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(strColorWind));
            else
                cardViewWind.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(strColorUnSelect));

            options.setSeries(seriesList);

            chartView.setOptions(options);
            chartView.reload();
            chartView.redraw();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

I have two items for displaying the chart one is date value and second one kwh value
List<String> dateFormatList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Float> usageList = new ArrayList<>();

I have verified the above list items also having the data, but the graph is not displaying.
In the logs, I am displaying the length if the araylist and getting some errors from high chart
E  @@@24 
E  @@@24
E  javascript:(function redraw() { chart.redraw(); })();
E  @@@24
E  @@@24
E  javascript:(function redraw() { chart.redraw(); })();
E  Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined
E  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'redraw')
E  Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined
E  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'redraw')
D  app_time_stats: avg=335.48ms min=20.52ms max=2265.75ms count=8
I  Native method called.
I  Native method called.


It looks like the Highcharts are not included properly in your project as the "Highcharts is not defined" error says. Make sure the library is available to use by adding a listener like this one: webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
view.loadUrl("javascript:setupChart()");
}
});
